Error when adding object using django admin "incorrect padding"
I was adding an Ad in the admin interface to use to test some template code. Previously, yesterday, I was able to add Ads no problem.  I log into admin, select add a new Add, then enter text into the CharField and TextFields of the model.  Worked always before today.  Now, I get an error.
Error at /admin/ads/ad/add/
Incorrect padding
I am using pythonanywhere.  Below is the traceback:
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://chabnet.pythonanywhere.com/admin/ads/ad/add/

Django Version: 4.2.7
Python Version: 3.10.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django_extensions',
 'crispy_forms',
 'crispy_bootstrap5',
 'rest_framework',
 'social_django',
 'taggit',
 'home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'ads.apps.AdsConfig',
 'knightshirt.apps.KnightshirtConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1886, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1792, in _changeform_view
    form_validated = form.is_valid()
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 201, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 196, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 435, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 486, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1470, in full_clean
    self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1522, in clean_fields
    setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 776, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/chabnet/.virtualenvs/django4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2647, in to_python
    return memoryview(b64decode(value.encode("ascii")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)

Exception Type: Error at /admin/ads/ad/add/
Exception Value: Incorrect padding

I am using Chrome.  I have tried clearing the cache, cookies, etc. many times.  After, clearing the cache several times.  It worked.  Then, returning and hour later, it produced the same error again. I cleared cache and cookies but it still produces the error.  It has something to do with base64 decoding but django is doing that behind the scenes (right?), my models use either CharField or TextField.  Why is it complaining now?
